# How do Maven Plugins like the Jetty-Maven-Plugin manage to keep their goals running until manually stopped?

Tags: maven-3, maven-plugin

I'm currently developing a Maven Plugin and wonder how some Plugins like the Jetty-Maven-Plugin manage to execute goals which require the user to stop them?

E.g. running

```
$ mvn jetty:run
```

starts an embedded Jetty but doesn't go through all of Maven's lifecycle and then stops.

I've tried creating a Thread to keep the goal running but this doesn't seem to be enough.

Comment: And why this doesn't seem to be enough? What exactly is going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question:

After reading the Jetty Maven Plugin source code it seems that the run goal calls

```
server.join()
```

on the Jetty server to pause the current thread until the Jetty server has finished execution.